# What could cause an Azure VM to stop responding completely?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I have an Azure Linux VM running MySQL, which has stopped responding for the past 24 hours - ping, SSH, MySQL and everything else timeout when trying to connect to it. Yet the status shows as 'Running' normally in the portal.

I've tried restarting the server, stopping/start the server, resizing it. All complete successfully, but make no difference. I also detached the VHD from the VM and created a new VM with it instead, but the new VM has the same problem. I guess this means the problem is with the VHD itself. It had been running well for a couple of months before this. The only change recently this was adding a new, blank WordPress database for a new site with no traffic yet.

Is there anything I'm missing that could cause such a problem, or any way to solve it? It's incredibly frustrating as all my sites are down with no fix in sight :(

Comment: I would try to debug the network connection. See first public IP config (ifconfig), firewall (iptables), tracepath. The gateway may be wrong or there is a firewall in between. Try outgoing connections (wget, ssh, telnet). If you don't find it I would try to contact support, because it may have an external reason.

Comment: I wonder when there is NO SSH, how could possible we check the iptables? also, plublic IP Address in Windows Azure VM is not accessible from the VM at all. The only meaningful part is the support request! You should contact support, there is no much you could do! The other option is to download the VHD locally and run it in your own virtualized environment (that can attach VHD) and inspect the OS.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this happen and it's an unfortunate situation. Sometimes when Microsoft patches the HyperV host that the VM runs on 3 things can happen if it fails to move it off before it reboots.

1. The VM goes down and comes up typically around 19 minutes later and all is fine.
2. The VM is hung in a funky state and requires you to force stop if via Powershell Azure commandlets. I blogged how to do this [here](http://www.solarcurve.com/2014/03/azure-outage-recovery.html).
3. An unfortunately thing happens much less often is that the VM itself is corrupt. You can't manage it, you can't get into it, and honestly I've found no way to fix it. I had to delete and rebuild the VM despite hours of trying to save it.

I realize this is an old post but wanted to provide a solution since I knew the answer in the hopes that it helps someone else as this still occasionally happens.